# How do I run my custom function in my plugin when a wordpress user is deleted?

Tags: plugins, users

I have a custom function in my plugin, I want to run it when any of the wordpress user is deleted so i can know that a user and which user was deleted.
I implemented this but it is'nt working.

```
 function my_delete_user( $user_id ) {
    global $wpdb;
    require_once(ABSPATH.'wp-admin/includes/user.php' );
        $user_obj = get_userdata( $user_id );
        $email = $user_obj->user_email;

    $headers = 'From: ' . get_bloginfo( "name" ) . ' <' . get_bloginfo( "admin_email" ) . '>' . "\r\n";
      wp_mail( $email, 'You are being deleted, brah', 'Your account at ' . get_bloginfo("name") . ' is being deleted right now.', $headers );
}
add_action( 'delete_user', 'my_delete_user' );
```

but this is not working, as it should send a mail. I want to know which user was deleted from their email.

Comment: You're setting `$email` to the _user's_ email. So you're emailing _them_ when their account is deleted. `wp_mail()` should us your email address as the first argument if you want to know when a user is deleted.

Comment: @JacobPeattie I created a user with the email i use but the wp_mail() is not sending any mail to my email, so should I believe that the function is not working?

Comment: Is that the account that you deleted?

Comment: a WP user account (subscriber), yes.

Comment: The first step is to prove whether or not your hook is working. Make this the first line of your function `echo 'success!'; die();` - if your function is hooked in properly, when you delete a user you should get a blank screen with just 'success' at the top.

Comment: @PeterHvD thanks, I can see my function is being called now.

Comment: great - at least you know that part works. Your implementation of `wp_mail` looks OK to me. Off the top of my head (ie, I can't test it right now) the 2 lines `global...` and `require_once...` look superfluous to me. Try removing them and see what happens.